# How to help template type inference

Tags: c++, templates

I have an abstract base class:

```
template<class T>
class Iterator
{
  public:
    virtual T operator*() = 0;
    ...
};
```

And I have a concrete subclass

```
template<class T,
         template<class, class> class Col,
         class Alloc = std::allocator<T>>
class StdIterator final: virtual public Iterator<T>
{
    typedef typename Col<T, Alloc>::iterator std_iterator;
    std_iterator b, e;
  public:
    StdIterator(Col<T, Alloc>);
    StdIterator(std_iterator, std_iterator);
    T operator*() const override;
    ...
};
```

At the callsite, I have code like `StdIterator<int, std::vector> x (a_std_vector)`.
How can I change the callsite to simply `StdIterator<std::vector<int>>> x (a_std_vector)`, and have it bind `T` based on the template parameter of `std::vector`? I do still need T, Col, and Alloc to all be bound within the class's body.

In addition to this, the code I have will only work for std::vectors, not std::sets etc. I've tried to get that functionality (using variadic class templates), but I can't even get it to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard container have `value_type` typedef, so you may use something like:

```
template<class C>
class StdIterator final: virtual public Iterator<typename C::value_type>
{
    typedef typename C::iterator std_iterator;
    // your stuff
};
```